# How can I deal with data creation that depends on response of a microservice?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, microservices

I have two microservices: one is responsible for manage players and the other is responsible for manage authentication/authorization. When I create a new player inside the player microservice I make a call to create the auth data like:

```py
auth_data = create_auth_object(data) # This will make a post in auth microservice
```

and after it I use the ID return from auth microservice to create players infos like:

```py
data_example = {
    auth_id: auth_data.get("id"), #sometimes auth_data is empty (explained below)
    name: "example",
    real: "example2"
}

create_player(data_example)
```

but sometimes the auth microservice return a timeout error (some GCP problem) and I cant create the player without the ID from auth microservice, but the auth data has been created in the database even I got the timeout error. So, if I try to create the player again I will receive an error that show the player already exists, but only the auth data exists, the player data was not created.

How is the proper way to deal with It? Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Why not ask for the auth data first, then create it only if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Both the player service and the auth service must handle this error and make the operation repeatable:

The auth service must accept another identical creation request and return an OK and the ID (but must of course not create another auth data set if it has been created before).

The player service must not try to create a player if there is no ID, but instead either automatically try again to call the auth service (fixed or dynamic/configurable number of attempts) or return an error to the user so the user can manually repeat the operation.